# How to extend a Zurb Foundation 6 Javascript Plugin?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

i want to extend the Zurb Foundation 6 Javascript Plugin without touching the original foundation.abide.js file, of course.

In an own file ownextend.abide.js i want to extend the

```
Abide.defaults = {
    labelSuccessClass:   "is-valid-label",
    inputSuccessClass:   "is-valid-input",
    formSuccessSelector: ".form-success",
    formSuccessClass:    "is-success"
    }
```

and extend the key/value-function object

addSuccessClasses, removeErrorClasses, [...]

```
var Abide = function () {

[...]

key: 'addSuccessClasses',
value: function addSuccessClasses($el) {
    // awesome code
}

[...]

return Abide;
}();
```

Somehow ...

Thanks in advance for some help.